# Is there a good tutorial on Websphere 6.1 ND deployments?

Tags: websphere

I need to deploy an application on the WAS ND 6.1 and do not know anything about it and cannot afford to go to training...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting started with WAS ND can be a bit overwhelming.  The redbooks mentioned above to give you a good introduction, especially the first few chapters but they are often over 500 pages long.  IBM also provides an educational assistant which is a presentation style overview and that may give a good point to start with.  The link to the educational assistant is shown below:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp

Answer (score 1):

There is the RedBook [WebSphere Application Server V6.1: System Management and Configuration](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247304.html?Open) with Chapter 14 talking about application deployment, this could help.

Answer (score 0):

This course from IBM would also be excellent but a bit pricy!!!

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247304.html?Open